# How to watermark a wave file with NAudio?

Tags: naudio

My application outputs wave files and I have the requirement to implement watermarking. By this I mean taking another wave file containing, say, 4 seconds of someone saying "This file is copyrighted material" and overlay this into the original file every 30 seconds.

I have tried many things but none quite works. I can pad the watermark to 30 seconds using `OffsetSampleProvider` and mix this with `MixingSampleProvider`, but that would only mix in one copy.

[`LoopStream`](https://markheath.net/post/mixing-and-looping-with-naudio) is a `WaveStream`, not an `ISampleProvider`, and even if I could do the conversion, I think this would mix forever, because the `LoopStream` would never stop returning data.

This seems like a fairly basic use case, but I cannot figure out how to do it!

Answer (score 0):

You're not too far off. You can turn a `LoopStream` into an `ISampleProvider` with the `ToSampleProvider` extension method, and then you can use the `Take` extension method to limit the duration of the looped stream to match the duration of the file you're mixing it with.